# `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, angular6, saas

Im tried to build my Angular 6 project in **Mac** but its not work, correctly work on **Windows** no any error, but cant run on the **mac** i had to face that type error

> Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4.
>   Please install a compatible version.

```
Node -v  8.11.3  (Mac)/ 8.11.3 (windows)

Npm -v 6.1.0(Mac) / 5.6.0(windows)
```

any one know how to fix that error on the mac

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this problem today, and find the the link is very helpful.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/563

Long story short, `npm rebuild node-sass` will fix the problem